# IOS to call javascript notify function

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c

My app is like iBook. Am loading the html files into the webview.

I have a html file loaded into webview..

```
 <img class="play_icon" src="images/play_icon.png" onclick="javascript:window.external.notify('Home pregnancy test.mp4')" />
```

How to call the javascript function window.external.notify() from objective c

How do i get this notify and get the video url in objective c

Answer (score 0):

Just see the solution below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function yourFunctionName()
            {
                alert("Hello World!");
            }
            </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button onclick="yourFunctionName()">Try it</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Your Obj-C code

```
NSString *path;
NSBundle *thisBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
path = [thisBundle pathForResource:@"first" ofType:@"html"];
NSURL *instructionsURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:instructionsURL]];

 NSString * jsCallBack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"yourFunctionName()"];
 [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCallBack];

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"yourFunctionName()"];
```

You need to implement the execution in the following way because implementing the above Obj-C in one place will not work. So you have to do it the following way. The reason is that the working will be in Asynchronous manner thats why

Call the following function in UIWebViewDelegate

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"yourFunctionName()"];
```

The call back method should be on –webViewDidFinishLoad:

If you need more information then have a look at the following link

[Using JavaScript From Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/Tasks/JavaScriptFromObjC.html)

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply.. But in my html there is no script file. I tried this way. Not working. Notify function is like alert without using script the webview will notify.. But i dont know how to call

Comment: You can write a javascript function in the same html file. Just write a sample fucntion and test if the call passes or not. Once the call is passed, you will be able to implement your requirement.

Comment: Hi i tried with the alert function. It is working fine. The alert pops up. But i dont know how to call this notify. In html they mention like onclick="javascript:window.external.notify('Home pregnancy test.mp4')"

Comment: When i mentioned onclick = "javascript:alert()" It works fine. But how do i call the above method and get the .mp3 file name from html file